# Phillips Hue REST API transition time for schedule POST not working

Tags: json, rest, philips-hue, home-automation

I am communicating with the my Phillips Hue REST API. I am trying to post a schedule with a transition time. This is ultimately what the JSON looks like before it's sent to the bridge:

```
"{"localtime":"2019-12-06T13:08:59","name":"Red","command":{"address":"/api/newdeveloper/groups/0/action","method":"PUT","body":{"hue":4000,"bri":1,"transitiontime":1000,"on":true}},"description":"description"}"
```

In theory, if my lights are set to a different color, the transition to this color should take (transitionTime / 10) seconds, or 100, seconds to transition to the posted color at the specified time according to the Hue API docs, but this does not happen. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something or missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I got errors from the Hue bridge when trying to set both transitiontime and bri_inc as a single action from a rule (despite documentation saying this should be possible). Is it possible that you're getting a similar error, but don't see it because the error is not triggered when the schedule is created, only when it's run?